# Configuring Restlet + JAX-RS-extension for Android

Tags: android, rest, jax-rs, restlet

Did anybody succed in configuring the [JAX-RS-extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/57-restlet.html) of [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) to make it work on Android? There is no Android-specific release of the extension, but I would like to try it nevertheless.

Since Android Restlet doesn't support the autodiscovery mechanism, I need to know which classes must be injected manually.

*Side Question (please answer with comment):* Is there another REST framework which will work with Android and JAX-RS? I tried an [unoffical Resteasy-Android-client](https://github.com/tdiesler/resteasy-mobile), but it throwed StackOverflowErrors all along.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with resteasy, and can't get Restlet to work with JAX-RS on Android either.